# Почему критическая секция не работает как мьютекс?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, mutex

У меня есть глобальная переменная global равная 100, и есть 2 потока, каждый из которых 12 раз увеличивает значение этой глобальной переменной, т.е. в итоге её значение должно быть равным 124. Сначала я использовал для синхронизации мьютекс и всё было отлично, т.к. потоки выполнялись поочерёдно. После я решил заменить мьютекс на критическую секцию, и вроде бы я в итоге получаю 124, но при этом потоки не выполняются поочередно чего я никак не мог ожидать, может быть кто-нибудь знает в чём тут дело?

Собственно код:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int global = 100;
HANDLE ht1, ht2; 
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(LPVOID lpParameter ) { 
    int i, j;   
    for (j=1; j <= 12; j++)    {        
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);   
        i = global;      
        i++;     
        Sleep (1);      
        global = i; 
        printf_s( "%4s %4d \n", " 1 th", i );     
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);   
    } 
    return 0;  
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2 (LPVOID lpParameter) { 
    int i, j; 
    for (j=1; j <= 12; j++)    {    
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);   
        i = global;      
        i++;     
        Sleep (1);     
        global = i;
        printf_s( "%4s %4d %4d \n", " 2 th", i, j );     
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);    
    } 
    return 0; 
} 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) { 
    HANDLE msh[2]; 
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    ht1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc1, NULL, 0, NULL); 
    ht2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc2, NULL, 0, NULL); 
    msh[0] = ht1; 
    msh[1] = ht2;
    Sleep(500);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
    return 0; 
}
```

Такой результат я получаю с использованием мьютекса:
[image: Результат с мьютексом]

А вот результат с использованием критической секции:
[image: Результат с критической секцией]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А с чего им выполняться поочередно? Выделено время до переключения - и пошел-пошел-пошел, сколько успеет... Поток переключился, пошел-пошел-пошел второй...

Возможное переключение при `Sleep(1)` **не** сработает - оно в критическом разделе. Так что у второго потока шанса запуститься по сути нет...
Вот один поток и гонит весь цикл, а потом второй.

А мьютекс у вас (код вы не привели, будем ванговать...) пропускает один поток, второй ждет. Мьютекс отпущен, второй тут же включился, первый на своей итерации влетает в ожидание. Второй отпускает - захватывает первый... Ну, и так далее. Без вашего кода трудно точно сказать.

А вот если вынести `Sleep` за пределы раздела - типа

```
for (j=1; j <= 12; j++)    {        
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);   
    i = global;      
    i++;     
    global = i; 
    printf_s( "%4s %4d \n", " 1 th", i );     
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);   
    Sleep (1);      
}
```

то результат уже не такой грустный :) -

```
 1 th  101 
 2 th  102    1 
 1 th  103 
 2 th  104    2 
 1 th  105 
 2 th  106    3 
 1 th  107 
 2 th  108    4 
 1 th  109 
 2 th  110    5 
 1 th  111 
 2 th  112    6 
 1 th  113 
 2 th  114    7 
 1 th  115 
 2 th  116    8 
 1 th  117 
 2 th  118    9 
 1 th  119 
 2 th  120   10 
 1 th  121 
 2 th  122   11 
 1 th  123 
 2 th  124   12
```

Именно потому, что `Sleep` обеспечивает переключение на второй поток...

Я более-менее доступно пояснил?

Только вот учтите, что **гарантии** поочередного выполнения этим переносом `Sleep()` не получится - есть теоретическая вероятность, что оба потока уйдут в спячку одновременно...

P.S. Убрал `Sleep` совсем, счетчик поднял до 1000 - получил до 123 первый поток, потом до 1122 второй, потом опять первый... Т.е. переключение есть - но именно такое, как я писал - по времени.

Comment: Да всё понятно, не знал, что есть время до переключения. Код с мьютексом идентичен представленному, за исключением того, что вместо EnterCriticalSection используется WaitForSingleObject, а вместо LeaveCriticalSection стоит ReleaseMutex.
Видимо до вашего ответа я неправильно представлял работу критической секции, я думал что как только первый поток дойдёт до LeaveCriticalSection второй сразу же войдёт в свой критический участок.

Answer (score 2):

Вся суть и назначение критической секции заключается в том, что захват *свободной* критической секции - исключительно легкая операция, выполняемая в контексте вызывающего процесса, без системных вызовов и переключения контекста. Попытка же захвата уже *занятой* критической секции - "тяжелая" операция, которая помещает поток в полноценное состояние системного ожидания - "спячки" (см. однако spin count ниже).

По этой причине, если поток, владеющий критической секцией, делает `LeaveCriticalSection` и `EnterCriticalSection` без какой-либо паузы между ними, у ждущего ("спящего") потока нет никаких шансов успеть вовремя проснуться и тоже сделать попытку захвата секции. Уже владеющий секцией поток будет все время единолично успешно освобождать и перезахватывать ее.

Именно это вы и наблюдаете в вашем эксперименте.

Чтобы уравнять шансы потоков, вам надо

- Либо ввести какую-то задержку между `LeaveCriticalSection` и `EnterCriticalSection`, чтобы дать ждущему потоку время проснуться до выполнения `EnterCriticalSection`.
- Либо позаботиться о том, чтобы ждущий поток не уходил в состояние системной спячки, пока первый поток "держит" секцию. Этого можно достичь путем указания spin count для критической секции. Разумеется, для такой тяжелой итерации, как у вас, понадобится неразумно большой spin count.

Тем не менее, ради эксперимента, в данном примере для облегчения итерации убираем `Sleep` и делаем

```
InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&cs, 10000000);
```

Получаем уже

```
 1 th  101
 2 th  102    1
 1 th  103
 2 th  104    2
 2 th  105    3
 2 th  106    4
 1 th  107
 2 th  108    5
 2 th  109    6
 1 th  110
 2 th  111    7
 2 th  112    8
 1 th  113
 1 th  114
 2 th  115    9
 1 th  116
 2 th  117   10
 2 th  118   11
 2 th  119   12
 1 th  120
 1 th  121
 1 th  122
 1 th  123
 1 th  124
```

А если убрать такую "тяжесть", как `printf` и следить за потоками более эффективными способами, то сработает и существенно меньший spin count.